# Why does my anchor link redirect to the same page?

Tags: html

I faced a problem using a link inside my main html and giving another html file name to the link which is in the same root as the main html.
unfortunately after click on the link the address bar is changed but the page is not loaded and it redirects to the main html page.
this is the way I wrote the link:

```
<a href="./PU.html">click</a>
```

this is my folder structure:

[image: file structure]

I also tried with giving the full path but I got this error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/my_project/templates/PU.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If `PU.html` is in the same folder/directory as your main/index file, then you don't need the `./`. Also, are your files on a server, or are you working on locally on your computer?

Comment: This behaviour is due to your HTTP server which is either redirecting your back to `/` or serving up the same file for every URL. We can tell you are using an HTTP server because otherwise you wouldn't get the error message from switching from HTTP to FILE. Since you haven't told us anything about your HTTP server there isn't much more we can do without more information. Expect this question to be closed if you don't edit it quickly enough to include enough information for people to help. (It can be reopened later once your edit comes in).

Comment: yes you are right, I am working locally on my computer

Comment: As Quentin said, you should edit your question to provide more information. What is your folder structure like? I see the `my_project/templates` in your full path, but where is your index.html in relation to the `PU.html`?

Comment: Details of the server itself are likely more important (he said, expecting this to be another duplicate of "I wrote my own HTTP server in Node.js which pays no attention to the path in the request" question).

Comment: I added my folder structure and edited my post, but I did not understand what should I add about HTTP server?

Comment: @Quentin could you please tell me how can I solve the problem of HTTP server?
because I think this is the source of my issue as you said

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments, I assume you're working locally on your computer, so I'm going to answer accordingly.

The first and foremost thing to know is that your ***main***, i.e the file you want users to see first should be named as **`index.html`** and it should be in the root directory of your project, i.e according to your question, it should be in `my_project`.

Now if it is as I said, then your `my_project` folder/directory will be considered as the **root** directory. With the help of this consideration, now you can set *links* with respect to the **root** directory. e.g:

```
<a href="/templates/PU.html">click</a>
```

The **`/`** at the beginning here tells the HTML to look from the root directory, i.e from `my_project` in your case.

---

I don't see any errors in the code you have. Though, I will tell you a few things here.
`**./**` at the beginning of the *link* tells HTML to look at the file in the same folder as of the present file. So, if the `PU.html` file is not in the **same folder** as of the file you're working on, it will give an error, because as I said, it's looking for the file in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Iwhen I set the links with respect to the root the page can not be found but I think the problem should be HTTP server that always redirects me to the root /

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax.

`<a href="./PU.html">click</a>` is **correct**,
but if you have your files in the same directory you don't need **./**.

Comment: "is correct" — It might be correct, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "f you have your files in the same directory you don't need ./." — While true, removing it won't make a difference.

Comment: When you have a little reputation, [you can comment on any question or answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) but you shouldn't use the Post An Answer feature for saying things that don't actually solve the problem in the meantime.

Comment: Extraneous files is not an issue, and there are previous answers that better answer this regarding paths (relative and absolute).  If you unclear about those terms, check out https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp.